# Why my Wifi adapter is not detecting any WiFi network in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

When I turn on the WiFi, it shows no network. I ran the command `sudo lshw -class network` and got the following result:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 05
       serial: e0:db:55:d8:f2:20
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c1404000-c1404fff memory:c1400000-c1403fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlp8s0
       version: 01
       serial: 9c:2a:70:52:fe:19
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-43-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.41 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:c1500000-c157ffff memory:c1580000-c158ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: bnep0
       serial: 9c:2a:70:52:fe:1a
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.136 multicast=yes
```

Comment: Generally, DISABLED means that the wireless radio is turned off by the wifi or Airplane Mode switch. Confirm: `rfkill list all` Please find the switch and turn on the wireless. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.